# How to add custom class as datasource and delegate to a NSTableView

Tags: ios, swift, macos, uitableview

I am writing an application for OSX in Swift. I use a NSTableView. 
I created a custom class which implements NSTableViewDataSource and NSTableViewDelegate. Now I would like to mark this custom class as delegate and datasource of my TableView but, I can’t find how to do that.

The only way I found out to do that is : Create un Ojbect in the interface builder. Add it in my view put my custom class as class of the object. And finally link the object as datasource and delegate of the TableView.

This way doesn’t seem to be clean. Does someone have an idea to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an instance of your custom class that implements those protocols where you have your NSTableView. Then set the delegate and datasource properties to the instance that you created

Comment: But in which method should I implement the delegate and the datasource? I tried to set it in the viewDidLoad Method but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

```
let myObject = MyClass()
tableView.delegate = myObject
```

That should do the trick. A bit cleaner than using Interface Builder.